# Cannot run gradle test tasks because of java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jdk/internal/reflect/GeneratedSerializationConstructorAccessor1

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, gradle

I have an android project where I cannot run anymore all the test gradle tasks locally (I have 3 different flavors in this project). I have this error message 50 times before the tasks fail. I have no issue running these tasks remotely with Gitlab CI/CD, and I have another project locally where I don't have this issue neither.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jdk/internal/reflect/GeneratedSerializationConstructorAccessor1
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedSerializationConstructorAccessor1.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.newInstance(ObjectStreamClass.java:1092)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2150)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1668)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:482)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:440)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.deserializeWorker(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:153)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:121)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:71)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)
```

Comment: im having the exact same issue, have you recently upgraded to the latest Jetbrains IDE versions by any chance? AS 4.2.1 i think

Comment: @davy307 Yes, I also recently updated Android Studio to 4.2.1 but I cannot date the issue, so I am not sure if this is related

Comment: Update: I have the issue on AS 4.2.1. Then I tried with the last version of IC 2021.1, at the begining intellij had gradle issues and did not want to compile the project. After going back and forth through the git history of my project, it somehow fixed the build issue with IC (without changing a line) and I can now build the project and run the tests with IC. The issue remains with AS.

Comment: right, so after some investigation, it turns out that AS 4.2.1 has an issue where it loses the reference to the JDK, now, depending on your project, you need to download the specific JDK version from oracle (for ours i used JDK 8 (https://www.oracle.com/uk/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html) as that is the max supported, then point AS to that as its JAVA_HOME under the Project Structure menu

Answer (score 111, accepted):

This is an old issue, but for future google searchers and perhaps interested parties that could work around this, it is worth mentioning that if you are using one of the more popular walk-throughs to set up JaCoCo + Robolectric + Espresso - https://medium.com/@rafael_toledo/setting-up-an-unified-coverage-report-in-android-with-jacoco-robolectric-and-espresso-ffe239aaf3fa . Please add below this:

```
tasks.withType(Test) {
    jacoco.includeNoLocationClasses = true
    jacoco.excludes = ['jdk.internal.*']
}
```

In my case:

```
junitJacoco {
    jacocoVersion = '0.8.4' // type String
    includeInstrumentationCoverageInMergedReport = true // type boolean
    tasks.withType(Test) {
        jacoco.includeNoLocationClasses = true
        jacoco.excludes = ['jdk.internal.*']
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks it worked for me. Also, the link you have mentioned is not reachable.

Comment: Spent so long trying to fix this and my issue was that I forgot the `*` wildcard at the end of `jdk.internal.*` ‍♂️

Comment: Thx! Adding jacoco.excludes = ['jdk.internal.*'] did the trick!

Answer (score 23):

Thanks to [@Tungken](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68139455/6478047)

I had to add it inside `testOptions { unitTests.all { jacoco {`

```
android {
  compileSdk 30
  buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

  defaultConfig {
 
     ...

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
       
    }
    debug {
        testCoverageEnabled true
        debuggable true
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '11'
}

testOptions {
    unitTests.all {
        jacoco {
            includeNoLocationClasses = true
            excludes = ['jdk.internal.*']       //This line
        }
    }
    unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks. For me it only worked when I added it inside : testOptions { unitTests.all { jacoco {

Comment: This solution worked for me, but nobody else on my team needed to add it - they could all run the tests just fine, and the tests also run fine in Jenkins. Therefore I don't want to commit this change to my repo. Does anyone know why only I need to make this change? There must be something I can change locally so I don't need to do this.

Comment: @elliptic1 I have the exact same issue.  Have you found a solution?

Comment: @elliptic1 Make sure the java version in your path matches your coworkers (that was my issue).

Answer (score 5):

In such case, even if your JAVA_HOME is set in bash_profile, you also need to set in Android, to do so:
Go to File -> Project Structure -> SDK location
set JDK location.

At times, it might a different location from bash_profile one.

Refer to screenshot for reference
[image]

Comment: This worked for me! I changed my JDK from 11 to 8 and now I can run the tests locally.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For anyone looking how the fix looks like in Kotlin `*.kts`:

```
tasks.withType<Test> {
    extensions.configure(JacocoTaskExtension::class) {
        isIncludeNoLocationClasses = true
        excludes = listOf("jdk.internal.*")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone looking how the fix look like for Kotlin DSL - working solution:

```
import com.android.build.gradle.BaseExtension
import org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.configure
import org.gradle.testing.jacoco.plugins.JacocoTaskExtension

configure<BaseExtension> {
    testOptions {
        unitTests {
            all { test ->
                test.extensions.configure<JacocoTaskExtension> {
                    excludes = listOf("jdk.internal.*")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```